# ¿es recomendable abrir conexion mysql cada vez que un usuario haga algo?

Tags: mysql, sql, nodejs, npm

Tengo un proyecto de nodejs en el que utilizo [npm mysql](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql), pero me ha surgido una duda y no sé que hacer, resulta que cada vez que el usuario hace algo que requiere base de datos, pues lo que hago es crear una conexión a la misma con `pool.getConnection();` y después de hacer todo lo que valla a hacer la destrullo con `connection.destroy();`

### Pregunta problema:

pero ahora lo que me pregunto es, en el caso de que bastantes usuarios esten requiriendo al mismo tiempo alguna accion que implique base de datos, sería recomendable estar creando conexiones por cada usuario?..

### Pregunta problema vol2:

Ahora, podría simplemente dejar una sola conexion cuando se inicia el servidor, pero me pongo a pensar y digo, si algún dia se cae la db?.. todas las consultas comenzarían a fallar, pero a la vez digo, si hago una conexión por cada usuario no sería contraproducente? o seria algo normal?..

Comment: Tal como está formulada tu pregunta, se basa en opiniones, lo cual ocasionará su cierre. En cuanto a tu duda, lo único que veo *extraño* es el hecho de que destruyas la conexión. Usualmente el flujo o patrón es: `pool.getConnection() -> connection.query() -> connection.release()`, es decir, no destruyes la conexión sino que la liberas, para que quede disponible para otro uso, a menos que necesites destruirla por motivos muy específicos (cerrar la conexión). Un *pool* de conexiones puede ser tan grande como tu memoria lo permita, además es lo usual cuando manejas multiusuarios. Saludos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Pool o conexión por request?**

La respuesta es NO, la idea de trabajar con pools de conexiones es que tu aplicación se conecta a la DB al iniciar la aplicación, crea tantas conexiones como hayas configurado en el pool y las mantiene vivas el tiempo que haga falta (las renueva si es necesario, vuelve a crearlas si alguna muere por alguna razón etcétera.

La ventaja es que no pierdes tiempo durante la ejecución de una petición estableciendo una conexión porque ya tienes un pool de conexiones listas.
Otra ventaja es que aprovechas mejor los recursos, lo normal es que una conexión a base de datos sea capaz de manejar varias consultas a la vez por lo que tener una conexión dedicada solo a una petición es poco óptimo.

Por ejemplo, en un entorno real tengo una aplicación manejando 200req/s con un pool de 15 conexiones a base de datos. Por lo que cada conexión maneja aprox. 13req/s.
Si no usase un pool de conexiones, tendría 200 conexiones por segundo que la DB debería estar manejando cuando es totalmente capaz de hacerl o que necesito con 15.

**Uso del pool en mysql nodeJS**

Dicho esto, si vamos a la documentación del paquete que comentas verás que hay una sección llamada [Pooling connections](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql#pooling-connections)

En dicha sección el ejemplo que usan es:

```javascript
var mysql = require('mysql');
var pool  = mysql.createPool({
  connectionLimit : 10,
  host            : 'example.org',
  user            : 'bob',
  password        : 'secret',
  database        : 'my_db'
});
 
pool.query('SELECT 1 + 1 AS solution', function (error, results, fields) {
  if (error) throw error;
  console.log('The solution is: ', results[0].solution);
});
```

Y añade:

> This is a shortcut for the pool.getConnection() -> connection.query()
> -> connection.release() code flow

Con esto podemos decir que usar `destroy` no es correcto.

Entonces, cuál es la diferencia entre `release` y `destroy`?
Destroy cierra la conexión contra la base de datos y la elimina del pool de conexiones. Cómo el pool está configurado para tener un mínimo de X conexiones creará una nueva por ti.

Para entender `release` debemos entender un poquito mas como funciona un pool de conexiones.

Cómo hemos comentado, un pool de conexiones mantiene vivas una cantidad X de conexiones. Pero también es el gestor de las mismas por lo que para usar dichas conexiones hay que pedirle al pool que nos de una, eso lo hacemos con `pool.getConnection()`. El pool marcará esa conexión como ocupada y no se la dará a nadie más hasta que la marquemos como liberada (con `connection.release()`)

En definitiva, hacer un `release` no tiene efecto ninguno sobre la base de datos, esta seguirá teniendo X conexiones abiertas. Es el pool a quien le interesa saber si estas conexiones se están usando o no.

**pool.query vs pool.getConnection**

Como hemos visto hay un método llamado `pool.query` que hace todo el flujo. Así que porqué utilizar `pool.getConnection`?

Cuando una petición hace varias queries contra la base de datos no hay necesidad de hacer que el pool nos asigne 2 conexiones distintas que vamos a liberar inmediatamente, así que podemos ser un poco mas listos y pedirle al pool que nos de una conexión, ejecutar las dos queries y devolver la conexión.